# In-built binary search not searching properly

Tags: c#, binary-search

So i'm trying to search and object array with the in-built "Array.BinarySearch" function in c# however, whenever I search for the text entered within a text box, I get the "Customer doesn't exist" message I implemented.

If anyone can help me that would be fantastic

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int found = Array.BinarySearch(cust, tbCUSTOMERID.Text);

    if (found == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Customer found!");
        tbCUSTOMERID.Text = cust[found].GScID;
        tbCUSTOMERNAME.Text = cust[found].GSname;
        tbCITY.Text = cust[found].GSlocation;
        tbEMAIL.Text = cust[found].GSemail;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Customer doesn't exist");
}
```

If you need anything else from me, hmu in the comments

*EDIT: The array is sorted, and the "cust" array is an object not a string

Comment: What is it that you think `Array.BinarySearch` does? Clearly `cust[found] == tbCUSTOMERID.Text` would return `false` because `cust` is a complex object, not a `string` (I'm assuming that `tbCUSTOMERID.Text` is a `string`).

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is a string, do you know of anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: @ZevSpitz it somewhat does not really matter - OP complains that unconditionally shown `MessageBox.Show("Customer doesn't exist");` is shown unconditionally... which is somewhat … expected behavior?

Comment: To avoid interrogation comments for next questions  please re-read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. It looks like your actual question is already answered on SO (which is either "find object by property" or "use binary search by property") and one of the linked duplicates should give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the item type of the `cust` array is something like this:

```
public class CustItem
{
    public string GScID { get; set; }
    public string GSname { get; set; }
    public string GSlocation { get; set; }
    public string GSemail { get; set; }
}
```

I'd recommend (assuming that GScID is unique) storing these values in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, not an array:

```
private IDictionary<string, CustItem> cust = new Dictionary<string, CustItem>();
cust.Add(item.GScID, item); // if you insert an existing key here, you will get a DuplicateKeyException
```

Then you can reference them by key:

```
if (cust.TryGetValue(tbCUSTOMERID.Text, out CustItem item))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Customer found!");
    tbCUSTOMERID.Text = item.GScID;
    tbCUSTOMERNAME.Text = item.GSname;
    tbCITY.Text = item.GSlocation;
    tbEMAIL.Text = item.GSemail;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Customer doesn't exist");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps clarify that `cust` itself is not `CustItem`, but rather `CustItem[]`.

Comment: @Zev My bad. Done.